# Likelihood ratio test: Negative degrees of freedom?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, likelihood-ratio, degrees-of-freedom

Why am I getting negative deviance and negative degrees of freedom in my likelihood ratio test?

"Day" has three levels.
"Line" has seven levels.

```
> summary(binary.main.glm)

Call:
glm(formula = Status ~ Line + Day, family = binomial, data = ParBin.data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.2174   0.4230   0.4813   0.5306   0.6495  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)    1.61774    0.74506   2.171   0.0299 *
LineCropper   -0.16892    0.78913  -0.214   0.8305  
LineDarling 1  0.27186    0.88602   0.307   0.7590  
LineDarling 4  0.42263    0.76476   0.553   0.5805  
LineDarling 5  0.69416    0.85240   0.814   0.4154  
LineWB275      0.65098    0.86032   0.757   0.4492  
LineZoar       0.05007    1.01720   0.049   0.9607  
Day2           0.05699    0.42837   0.133   0.8942  
Day3           0.70833    0.88860   0.797   0.4254  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 221.67  on 305  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 217.74  on 297  degrees of freedom
AIC: 235.74

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

> anova(binary.main.glm, update(binary.main.glm, . ~ Line), test="LRT")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: Status ~ Line + Day
Model 2: Status ~ Line
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
1       297     217.74                     
2       299     218.47 -2 -0.73524   0.6924
```

Comment: The difference in degrees of freedom between "Model 1" and "Model 2" is 2 (299 - 297). It is -2 because of the order you've put the models in `anova`. The documentation of the function `anova` says "It is conventional to list the models from smallest to largest, but this is up to the user." Try reversing the order of the models and the degrees of freedom will be +2.

Comment: Aaaaand I feel like an idiot.  You're spot on.  Thanks for the help!  (I'd been doing it this way with GLMMs and it never returned negative df's before so it's something I wouldn't have thought about.)